# Python - Removing all occurrences of a character only when it appears before non-capitalized words

Tags: python, regex, string, replace

I have the following string:

```py
mystring= "Foo some \n information \n Bar some \n more \n information \n Baz more \n information"
```

I would like to keep "\n" only when it precedes a word that starts with a capital letter. I would like to remove all other instances of "\n" in my sentence.

Desired output:

```py
"Foo some information \n Bar some more information \n Baz more information"
```

Is there a way to do this with re.sub? I can think of trying to split the words and use the `word[0].isupper()` argument. However, I believe there may be a way to identify Capital words with regex.

Comment: _However, I believe there may be a way to identify Capital words with regex._ Have you tried anything, done any research?

Comment: @AMC, I looked at the regex documentation and tried to search for similar questions. I wasn't able to find an explanation for my problem, so I asked here. Is there an issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this negative lookahead regex:

```
>>> mystring = "Foo some \n information \n Bar some \n more \n information \n Baz more \n information"
>>> print (re.sub(r'\n(?! *[A-Z]) *', '', mystring))
Foo some information
 Bar some more information
 Baz more information
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `\n`: Match a line break
- `(?! *[A-Z]) *`: Negative lookahead to assert we don't have an upper case letter after optional spaces. match 0 or more spaces afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

If the text may span paragraphs (notwithstanding the reference to "sentence" in the question), you could use the regex

```
 *\n *(?!\n*[A-Z])
```

(with a space preceding the first `*`).

Matches are replaced with a single space.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pCsX7R/2/)

This performs the following operations:

```
 *            * match 0+ spaces 
\n            * match a newline char
 *            * match 0+ spaces
(?!\n*[A-Z])  * match 0+ newlines followed by an uc letter
              * in a negative lookahead
```

As shown at the link, the text

```
Now is the time for all good regexers
to social distance themselves.
Here's to negative lookbehinds!

And also to positive lookbehinds!
```

becomes

```
Now is the time for all good regexers to social distance themselves.
Here's to negative lookbehinds!

And also to positive lookbehinds!
```

even though the newline character following `negative lookbehinds!` is not followed directly by an upper case letter, but by another newline followed by an upper case letter.

If the string ends with a newline it will be removed. That's because I'm using a negative lookahead rather than a positive one.